# Get <td> cell value using jQuery without specifying specific class or id

Tags: ruby, html-table, sinatra, erb

I am using ERB templating in Sinatra to display a table of data.

How can I use jQuery to get table data of a specific row when I click the EDIT button without having to assign specific class or ids to each `<td>` or `<tr>`?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>question</td>
    <td>answer</td>
    <td>edit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>What is a carrot?</td>
    <td>A vegetable</td>
    <td>
      <a id="editbutton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="editModal()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal4" aria-hidden="true" name="btn"  data-modal-type="confirm"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>What does HTML stand for?</td>
    <td>Hyper Text Markup Language</td>
    <td>
      <a id="editbutton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="editModal()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal4" aria-hidden="true" name="btn"  data-modal-type="confirm"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE:

I have managed to get the following to get the value in the nearest `<td>`

```
$('.editbutton').click(function(e) {
    var output = $(this).closest('tr').find('.as').text();
    alert(output);
  });
```

but I need values from both table data cells in that row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.closest()` , check API https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to use the following to get the nearest <td> 
    `$('.editbutton').click(function(e) {
    var output = $(this).closest('tr').find('.as').text();
alert(output);
  });`
but I need both of the <td> in the row. How can I get both not just the one closest?

Comment: @Mohammad Use a [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: @Mohammad Mark it as answered, please.